# zsh: How to store the return code of a statement without triggering `set -e`?

Tags: shell, zsh, exit-status

Suppose I want to capture the return code of

```
(exit 56)
```

If I use `set -e` or a `zerr` handler, I can no longer do:

```
(exit 56)
ret=$?
```

If I use `(exit 56) || true` to avoid `set -e`, the return code would become zero and I can no longer get it.

So how do I get the return code?

Comment: Related (though for `bash`): [Which is more idiomatic in a bash script: \`|| true\` or \`|| :\`?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/78408)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `&& true` instead:

```
set -o errexit
(exit 50) && true
echo code: $?
```

Though you could also do:

```
set -o errexit
if (exit 50) then else
  echo failed with code $?
fi
```

Or:

```
set -o errexit
(exit 50) || {
  code=$?
  echo failed with code $code
  # and whatever else you want to do with $code
}
```

The idea is that `errexit` is cancelled whenever the failing command is used as a *condition*, but if you do `(exit 50) && true`, the exit code after that would always be 0.

<sup>(personally, I avoid `errexit` and prefer doing proper error handling by hand).</sup>

Comment: These look like they should work in a standard shell or Bash too, apart from the empty `then` block, right? That would need to be changed to `then true; else` (or so) for those other shells.

Comment: @ilkkachu, yes though you'd also need to quote the parameter expansions that are in list context there as usual.